# Javascript replace() using html entities

Tags: javascript, replace, html-entities

For some reason, the Javascript `replace('search', 'replace')` function works for some HTML entity strings as a search term, but others it does not the way I expect it to. These inconsistencies are very problematic and I can't even work around the issue with the way it works. How can I guarantee these entity search terms will always find the full plain-text word? I need the replace to work the way `&dash;` does in this example:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#good').html($('#good').html().replace($('#good').data('text'), 'FOUND'));
  $('#okay').html($('#okay').html().replace($('#okay').data('text'), 'FOUND'));
  $('#bad').html($('#bad').html().replace($('#bad').data('text'), 'FOUND'));
  $('#wrong').html($('#wrong').html().replace($('#wrong').data('text'), 'FOUND'));
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="good" data-text="find">
1: find
</div>
<div id="okay" data-text="&dash;">
2: &dash;
</div>
<div id="bad" data-text="&gt;">
3: &gt;
</div>
<div id="wrong" data-text="&amp;">
4: &amp;
</div>
```

Comment: Have you tried `.text()` instead of `.html()`?

Comment: What are the inconsistencies you are having?

Comment: Tried you're example with @vlaz suggestion of replacing `.html()` with `.text()`. Works perfectly...

Comment: @MB run the code snippet. OP basically wants to replace the HTML content with...the HTML content replaced with the string `FOUND`

Comment: Sure enough, `.text()` fixes the problem!

Comment: @Siphon in general, try to avoid referencing and editing HTML directly, if it can be avoided. I'll be frank, I didn't even completely read you question, I just noticed that your code sample had `.html()` and I automatically suggested using `.text()` instead. Then I completely read the question. And then I started thinking about it. And then I realised `.text()` was actually going to work. At first my comment was simply to suggest not editing HTML directly, as it usually leads to problems sooner or later. In your case, _that_ happened to be the problem.

Comment: @vlaz Agreed, but editing the HTML cannot be avoided in this case. I find `html()` works in a most of my code, but apparently it has some quirks that cause headaches when you least expect them. Thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: @Siphon yes, those quirks are exactly what I meant. And yeah, the major deal of JS _is_ to manipulate HTML, I don't disagree. It's just that `$.html()` and `.innerHTML`/`.outerHTML` (in plain JS) and so on are usually not what you actually want. `$.text()` or `.textContent` (and others) still manipulate the DOM but it's much safer and less likely to cause headaches.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `.text()` instead of `.html()`,as @vlaz suggested. I ran the example using `.text()`, and it worked fine:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#good').text($('#good').text().replace($('#good').data('text'), 'FOUND'));
  $('#okay').text($('#okay').text().replace($('#okay').data('text'), 'FOUND'));
  $('#bad').text($('#bad').text().replace($('#bad').data('text'), 'FOUND'));
  $('#wrong').text($('#wrong').text().replace($('#wrong').data('text'), 'FOUND'));
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="good" data-text="find">
1: find
</div>
<div id="okay" data-text="&dash;">
2: &dash;
</div>
<div id="bad" data-text="&gt;">
3: &gt;
</div>
<div id="wrong" data-text="&amp;">
4: &amp;
</div>
```